# Password reset link gives access denied

Tags: 8, users

Password reset link is not working in drupal 8.6. The email with the one-time login link is sent just fine, but when the user clicks on the Login button, they get "You are not authorized to access this page" message. Even I tried to open `user/reset/{id}` with login as admin still same error. When I figuring out the issue I found one line in `user.module line no 556
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('user_login', [$account]);` is causing the issue. **If** I remove this line then I can reset my password successfully. whats this line is doing? Does it load all active modules in website? than there must be issue in any module. Could I remove this line? Any alter solution?

I tried by clearing cache,cookie, browser history, session table, also `$cookie_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` this line is not in my settings.php

Comment: Take a backup of your site, then start disabling modules one at a time, and try the password reset in between each one, until you figure out which module is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whats this line is doing? Does it load all active modules in website?

It invokes a hook ([`hook_user_login`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/8.6.x)), which other installed modules can respond to. It doesn't "load" any modules, but those other installed modules are already available at that point, yes.

> Could I remove this line?

Physically, yes, but it would be a terrible idea. It's important, or it wouldn't be there.

> Any alter solution?

You need to debug your site, preferably with a step-debugger like XDebug. Chances are you have a rogue custom or contributed module doing something it shouldn't be.

Comment: If it can help anybody my issue is I am redirecting user on some condition in my custom module which causing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Had similar outcome but issue was purely that the User record was still set to Blocked rather than Active.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with symfony/http-foundation v3.4.24. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3045844

Source: [Drupal 8 dropping session variables on password reset. Gives 403 Access Denied](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278697/drupal-8-dropping-session-variables-on-password-reset-gives-403-access-denied)